# How to use appUrlOpen on Nuxt x Capacitor App

Tags: nuxt.js, deep-linking, capacitor

I'd like to add deeplink settings to Capacitor app based on Nuxt and am sure that It need this settings below.

```
App.addListener('appUrlOpen', function (event: URLOpenListenerEvent) {
  // Example url: https://beerswift.app/tabs/tabs2
  // slug = /tabs/tabs2
  const slug = event.url.split('.app').pop();

  // We only push to the route if there is a slug present
  if (slug) {
    router.push({
      path: slug,
    });
  }
});
```

However my project use Nuxt2, not vue-router.

I wondered that addListener need to be added in nuxt.config.js but couldn't find solution.

Does anyone know how to use them?

I'm sorry my poor English and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, it's a plugin, so remember to configure it properly in nuxt.config.js

```
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core'
import { App } from '@capacitor/app'

export default ({ app }) => {
  if (process.client && Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (event) => {
      console.log('App opened with URL: ', event.url)

      // Treat your URL here

      // Navigate using the router
      try {
        app.router.push(...)
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Failed to navigate:', error)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The only problem with this is that if you open a deep link an when the app is not running it won't redirect the user, I'm still trying to solve this problem, but I hope this helps a little

Comment: It doesn't work the way it was supposed to but this idea is new to me and really helps! Thank you so much